# Thymeleaf + jQuery , how to properly add th:field="*{value}"

Tags: javascript, java, html, thymeleaf

I am struggling with a problem. I am trying to dynamically add row to my form. My first row (static) of form is working fine, but when I add another one, the form is being added but I cannot obtain any value, like it would stay empty. Please help

**OK it is my form:**

```
<h2>Risk management</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
        <tr>
            <th>Type of work</th>
            <th>Type of threat</th>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Intial risk</th>
            <th>Countermeasure</th>
            <th>Final risk</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <th><input type="text" th:field="*{typeOfWork}" /> </th>
            <th><input type="text" th:field="*{typeOfThreat}" /> </th>
            <th><input type="text" th:field="*{person}" /> </th>
            <th><input type="text" th:field="*{initialRisk}" /> </th>
            <th><input type="text" th:field="*{countermeasure}" /> </th>
            <th><input type="text" th:field="*{finalRisk}" /> </th>

        </tr>
        <button type="button" onclick="addFields()">Insert new row</button>
    </table>
```

**When I add row by using jQuery, row is added but the values written in form are not being sent to Model by Thymeleaf**

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

function addFields()
{
    document.getElementById("myTable").insertRow(-1).innerHTML = 
        '                <th><input type="text" th:field="*{typeOfWork}" /> </th>\n' +
        '                <th><input type="text" th:field="*{typeOfThreat}" /> </th>\n' +
        '                <th><input type="text" th:field="*{person}" /> </th>\n' +
        '                <th><input type="text" th:field="*{initialRisk}" /> </th>\n' +
        '                <th><input type="text" th:field="*{countermeasure}" /> </th>\n' +
        '                <th><input type="text" th:field="*{finalRisk}" /> </th>';
}
```

Comment: i am facing the same problem. Please suggest how i get the values from newly added text field using jquery..

Comment: remove th:field from javascript and use name instead of th:field, hope you will get the values in controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Thymeleaf` is compiled on the `server` while `Jquery` is processed at the `client`. All that the user receives on the `client` side is that the html does not include `Thymeleaf` in it. You can not use `JQuery` to add rows with the `Thymeleaf` code in it.

The solution here is to use an `Ajax` call to the `server` to retrieve the data for the new row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove that DIV with the "container" id of the table.

Comment: yeah, sign of previous attempts :)

Comment: OK, cleaned, Any other ideas?